# Alternative to Cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am looking for an alternative way to using a cursor for a stored procedure. Instead of selecting each Database (LAL, SINC, SMSS) like I do below, I would like to select a list of strings from a separate table and insert them into the @rates table, joined with there corresponding db/table. Is there a way to do this with a join, or will I need to write this with Dynamic SQL/Cursor?

I'm looking for possible solutions and appreciate all advice. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @rates TABLE
(
    DB       CHAR(5),
    FUTASUTA CHAR(3),
    DSCRIPTN CHAR(31),
    FUSUTXRT DECIMAL(18,4)
)

-- LAL Rates
INSERT INTO @rates 
    SELECT 'LAL', FUTASUTA, DSCRIPTN, (CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4),FUSUTXRT))/10000000 as FUSUTXRT 
    FROM [LAL].[dbo].[UPR40100]

-- SINC Rates
INSERT INTO @rates 
    SELECT 'SINC', FUTASUTA, DSCRIPTN, (CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4),FUSUTXRT))/10000000 as FUSUTXRT  
    FROM [SINC].[dbo].[UPR40100]

-- SMSS Rates
INSERT INTO @rates 
    SELECT 'SMSS', FUTASUTA, DSCRIPTN, (CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4),FUSUTXRT))/10000000 as FUSUTXRT  
    FROM [SMSS].[dbo].[UPR40100]

....etc
```

The table with Distinct databases is a simple table with names/id's

id | Name

1  | LAL

2  | SINC

3  | SMSS

etc...

Comment: You could use UNION ALL

Comment: Do you mean that the number of databases are dynamic and you want to query them dynamically instead of querying one by one?

Comment: @RezaRahmati - Yes. The list of databases could grow in my corporate_entity table. I need a way to write this so that as my DB's grow, I don't have to alter my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following method will work for you :

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(DBNAME VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @DYNAMICQUERY VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('LAL')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('SINC')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('SMSS')

SET @DYNAMICQUERY = 
(
SELECT 'INSERT INTO @rates SELECT '''+ DBNAME +''', FUTASUTA,DSCRIPTN, (CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,4),FUSUTXRT))/10000000 as FUSUTXRT FROM ['+ DBNAME + '].[dbo].[UPR40100];'
FROM @TABLE
FOR XML PATH('')
)

EXEC(@DYNAMICQUERY)
```

Comment: @HKImpact Let me know if this is helpful to you.

Comment: I'm getting an error when executing the @dynamicquery variable. Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@rates". It is declared, but i'm wondering if you can use a table variable like i did.

Comment: I changed @rates to a temp table instead of a table variable and still received an error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '&'.

Comment: I got that. Its due to enter charecter in select query. I just modified my ans. Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks Hiren! That seemed to work and was a better alternative to a cursor for me. I can't believe I didn't see the concatenation error... haha